# How to apply a filter for each row of the same queryset on Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have the a model Product which has a relation with itself using the key "parent".

This way, to get the parent of a product i just do `product.parent` and if i want the children of a product i do `product.product_set.all()`.

What i want to do is to do an annotate on a queryset of parent products and sum the stock of each product with the stock of its children. Something similar to this:

```
qs = Product.objects.filter(is_parent=True)
qs = qs.annotate(stock_sum=Sum(Product.objects.filter(parent_id=F('id')).values_list['stock']))
```

Is this possible? Will it result in many queries or django know a way of handling this with a few joins?

Answer (score 1):

Save for one syntax error (square brackets rather than parentheses after `values_list`) this should work as you intended.

This induces only a single query. Note you can check the SQL that the ORM generates by accessing the `.query` property of the queryset (the following was subsequently run through a SQL pretty-printer):

```
>>> str(qs.query)
SELECT
    "yourapp_product"."id",
    "yourapp_product"."parent_id",
    "yourapp_product"."stock",
    SUM((SELECT U0."stock" FROM "yourapp_product" U0 WHERE U0."parent_id" = (U0."id"))) AS "stock_sum"
FROM
    "yourapp_product"
WHERE
    "yourapp_product"."is_parent"
GROUP BY
    "yourapp_product"."id",
    "yourapp_product"."parent_id",
    "yourapp_product"."stock";
```